# working with json data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have the follow code that parses JSON data received from a server:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSArray *array_webdata=[[NSArray array] init];

NSString *searchStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

array_webdata = [parsedata objectWithString:searchStatus error:nil];

NSDictionary *usersList = [array_webdata valueForKey:@"results"];
```

//I think that is not a real NSDictionary because if I write **NSArray *keys = [usersList allKeys];** the execution crashes

```
NSLog(@"\n usersList =\n %@ \n", usersList);

[searchStatus release];
[connection release];
[webData release];
[pool drain];}
```

the json data stored in usersList has the structure:

```
(
{

  createTime = "date hour";

  fullname = "user name";

  "prof_id" = number;

   thumb = "image.jpg";

 },
 {
      data of rest of users...
 }
 )
```

And I would like create a class to store the data of each user and use "prof_id" when I want to use a particular use.
I need this because the app needs a list with all users (not tableview) and I think this is de easiest way.

Can someone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: why crashes if I write     NSArray *keys = [usersList allKeys]; ??? The error message says: [__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6863270

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please used [JsonKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) Framework to parse json data received from web service.

Read data and parse using JSONKit:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithData:webData];
JSONDecoder* decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc]
                             initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
NSArray* json = [decoder objectWithData:jsonData];
```

After that, you'll have to iterate over the json variable using a for loop.
Create new class with the name `User` (file->new->file) inherited from NSObject class, create required parameters in .h/.m file.(do synthesize to generate getter/setter for attributes)

import User.h in your connection class and create objects of User entity in iterator loop and add those object in global scope array.

```
for(NSDictionary *userInfo in json) {
   User* user=[[User alloc] init];
   user.fullName=[userInfo valueForKey:@"fullname"];
   user.prof_id=[[userInfo valueForKey:@"prof_id"] integerValue];
   // Add into your global array
  [usersList addObject:user];
  [user release];// if ARC is not enable
}
// Check for successful object creation
NSLog(@"USER LIST contain User class Objects- %@",userList);
```

Comment: I don't have problems parsing json data, my problem is that I don't know how to create a class to store this data and work with it

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, what code would be put in user.h and user.m?

Comment: I've been investigating, in a NSDictionary only pairs of values ​​can be saved if I understand correctly. What I need is to keep the four data for each user, I think a NSDictionary would not be correct. Am I right?

Comment: See you can save four information in Dictionary also, user as key and in value it will store array of this 4 values and 1 import point please read apple's guideline for objective c to handle OOP's concept, creating classes, handling objects, its very crucial nano.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mayur, I'm starting in this world and I find hard even the easiest things ;)

Answer (score 1):

if i'm not wrong the only thing you need to do is :

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = usersList;
```

and then with a for loop like

```
for(int i = 0;i<[usersList count] ;i++)
{
NSMutableDictionary *yourDictionary = [usersList objectAtIndex:i];
int prof_id = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"prof_id"];
}
```

you can get your prof_id like that.

i hope this helps...

Comment: You only can store **objects** with keys in Dictionary, not the float, int datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON Framework, and parse data using below code.

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yout link to json file"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"new str - %@",newStr);

NSArray *response = [newStr JSONValue];

NSLog(@"json array - %@",response);
```

Use the response array to show your results.